# ModelForm with multiple child models

Tags: python, django

I am working on an django invoice application. I have defined my models as follows:

```
from django.db import models

from clients_area.models import Company

class Invoice(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.number + ' ' + self.text    

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=1)

    def total(self):
        total = Decimal(str(self.unit_price * self.quantity))
        return total.quantize(Decimal('0.01'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

I would like to have an add invoice form, but am having some conceptual problems. How would I define a Invoice ModelForm that allows inserting InvoiceItems at creation time?

I believe I am going in the right direction with:

```
InvoiceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Invoice,
    InvoiceItem
    )
```

but the resulting form is missing all the Invoice models related inputs. What am I missing?

Comment: And how do you handle the formset in the view and in the template?

Comment: @petkostas I haven't started working on the POST section of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following view:

```
def add_invoice(request):
    InvoiceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Invoice, InvoiceItem)
    if request.POST:
        invoiceForm = InvoiceForm(request.POST) 
        invoiceFormSet = InvoiceFormSet(request.POST)
        if invoiceForm.is_valid() and invoiceFormSet.is_valid():
            invoice = invoiceForm.save()
            invoiceItems = invoiceFormSet.save(commit=False)
            for invoiceItem in invoiceItems:
                invoiceItem.invoice = invoice
                invoiceItem.save()
            return redirect('show_invoice', invoice_id=invoice.id)
    else:
        invoiceForm = InvoiceForm()
        invoiceFormSet = InvoiceFormSet()
    context_data = {
            'invoiceForm': invoiceForm,
            'invoiceFormSet': invoiceFormSet,
            }
    return render(request, 'add_invoice.html', context_data)
```

Probably there is a better way to handle this situation, please do answer if you have a better approach.